# Prove $(\Re{z_1})^2+(\Re{z_2})^2+(\Re{z_3})^2 < \frac{3}{2}$ for solutions of $4z^3-4z^2+12z-1=0$

Tags: functions, inequality, complex-numbers

**The statement of the problem** : Let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ be the solutions of the equation $$4z^3-4z^2+12z-1=0$$ Prove that : $(\Re{z_1})^2+(\Re{z_2})^2+(\Re{z_3})^2 < \frac{3}{2}$ ($\Re x$ is the real part of the complex number x)

**My approach :** We consider the function $f(x)=4x^3-4x^2+12x-1$ and we prove that it is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$.Let $x,y \in \mathbb R $ with $x>y$ . Now we prove that $f(x)-f(y)>0$ $$f(x)-f(y) = 4x^3-4y^3 - (4x^2-4y^2) + 12x - 12y -1 + 1 =$$ $$=(x-y)(4x^2+4y^2+4xy-4x+4y+12)=$$ $$(x-y)(4((x-\frac{1}{2})^2 +(y-\frac{1}{2})^2+xy+\frac{1}{2})+8)$$ which is obviously strictly greater than $0$.

Now $f(0)=-1<0$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=4,5 > 0$ , and from the fact that the function is strictly increasing, we get that $z_1 \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ . So the other $2$ roots are complex and $z_3=\bar{z_2}$ (the conjugate of $z_2$).I tried to apply the Vieta's formulas but I got stuck. I think I made some progress showing that a root is real and determining its interval and I think I am close to the answer.

**IDEA** since $z_3=\bar{z_2} \implies (\Re{z_3})^2 = (\Re{\bar{z_2}})^2 = (\Re{z_2})^2 $ . Using the interval of $z_1$, it is enough to show that $2(\Re{z_2})^2 < 1 \iff \Re{z_2} < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $ (I think that the interval of $z_1$ can be reduced and thus the demonstration becomes easier, but I am not sure at all)

I am open to your ideas and solutions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please stop cheating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that $z_1 = a$ is real with $a \in (0, \frac 12)$, and $z_{2, 3} = b \pm ic$ are complex conjugates.

Then $a+2b = z_1+z_2 + z_3 = 1$ from Vieta's formulas, so that
$$
(\Re{z_1})^2+(\Re{z_2})^2+(\Re{z_3})^2 = a^2 + 2 b^2  = a^2 + 2\left( \frac{1-a}{2}\right)^2 = \frac 32 a^2 - a + \frac 12 \, .
$$
$g(a) = \frac 32 a^2 - a + \frac 12$ is a convex function (a parabola) and attains its maximum on the interval $[0, \frac 12]$ at one of the boundary points. It follows that
$$
(\Re{z_1})^2+(\Re{z_2})^2+(\Re{z_3})^2 \le \max(g(0), g(\frac 12)) = \frac 12 \, ,
$$
which is a better estimate.

*Remark:* that $f$ is strictly increasing on $\Bbb R$ (and therefore has only one real zero) follows also from the fact that
$$ 
f'(x) = 12 x^2 - 8 x + 12 = 12 \left( (x- \frac 13)^2 + \frac 89\right)
$$
is strictly positive for all $x \in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a computer based answer with Mathematica 14.

```
sol = Solve[4*z^3 - 4*z^2 + 12*z - 1 == 0, z];
ToRadicals[Total[Table[Re[z]^2 /. sol[[k]], {k, 1, 3}]]]
```

$$\frac{1}{36} \left(\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{4233}-73}-\frac{32}{\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{4233}-73}}+2\right)^2+2 \left(-\frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{4233}-73}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{8}{3 \sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt{4233}-73}}\right)^2 $$

We directly compute the sum under consideration. And finally

```
N[%]
```

$$0.425417 $$

Comment: Thank you for your help !